# USB OTG Type-C vs 3.0 USB C OTG Thunderbolt 3

Tags: usb, железо

Не понимаю, зачем нужен переходник с type-c на type-c - разъёмы одинаковые и он не изогнутый, т. е. кажется, что он просто является удлинителем на 2 см, что странно.

[image]
[image]

Название:

> CABLETIME NEW USB OTG Type-C Adapter to 3.0 USB C OTG Thunderbolt 3 USB Type C Adapter Cable for Macbook Pro Samsung S9 C013

Описание:

> Cabletime USB C Type-c USB Type C Adapter USB 3.1 Male Adapter connects USB-C enabled device such as letv Smartphone, Nokia N1 tablet to a computer or USB charger for data transfer or charging with a Type-c cable. It upgrades your type-c  USB charging cable to a USB 3.1-Type C Data Cable and charging cable, saving you the cost of buying a new one. Connectors

По описанию получается, что он может "научить" кабель, работающий только для зарядки, передавать данные? Но разве такое возможно? В названии говорится, что это переходник с USB OTG Type-C на 3.0 USB C OTG Thunderbolt 3 - они чем-то между собой отличаются? И совместимы ли без переходника?

Во всех 11 отзывах стоит оценка 5 из 5, в некоторых даже написано, что всё работает, но никто так и не объяснил что же именно там работает. Зачем нужен такой переходник?

Если интересует ссылка: `https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/4000040214907.html`

Comment: Может кросс? Для телефонов которые не умеют отг кроссировать сами

Comment: @eri, а можешь подробнее? Я не понимаю так...

Comment: В usb есть мастер и сэйв. В 5 проводном мини Усб перестановкой провода определялось что воткнуто в телефон. Флешка, мышка или компьютер. В усб3 наверное такая же схема

Comment: @eri, так что он делает в таком случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот картинка для переходника OTG на разъем AF. Тут для перевода USB порта в режим host используется подпитка вывода CC через резистор. Type-C коннектор был изначально для ноутбуков Эпл и режим "хост" на нем был по умолчанию и питание постоянно. Под эту спецификацию стали выпускать устройства.

В современных устройствах этот резистор должен быть впаян в разъеме, но если подключить такое устройство через кабель в котором линия CC не заведенна или устройство не соответствует спецификации 3.1, то телефон не станет подавать питание и оно не заработает. Этот переходник говорит телефону включить питание.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Т. е. они разрывают один контакт?

Comment: разрывают и подпитывают

Comment: Разве тогда каждое устройство не будет считать себя главным? Или так и задумано?

Comment: со стороны телефона подпитывается cc и он считает себя главным, со стороны отг cc висит в воздухе и устройство считает себя ведомым

Comment: по современным спецификациям мне кажется этот резистор должен быть подпаян на флешку, мышку или что там они ещё вставляют..) но кабель может быть 4х проводный заложен в эту мышку - те usb2 с разъемом type-c... вот этим переходником фиксят совместимость

Comment: Стоп.. Что значит подача тока? Тот, кто подаёт - мастер или раб?

Comment: мастер. но телефон по умолчанию в режиме "забирать ток" стоит. вот контроллер видит что между сс и vcc резистор подтянут и переводит в режим мастера и на отдачу питания.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102439/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-eri).